# Generate x-mod-nonce in php

Tags: php, nonce

According to some documentation that I am currently looking in I need to set a header with label x-mod-nonce to a unique value per request with
example header:

```
x-mod-nonce: 28154b2-9c62b93cc22a-24c9e2-5536d7d
```

I thought of using
[uniqid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function do get this type of value but don't think I quite understand it.

Can someone hint some example of how can I do it or refer me to how to do it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to set a header with label x-mod-nonce to a unique value per request with example header

- Generate your **unique value** string with something like [random_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)
- Concatenate it to your header string
- Set your header with [header()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-header-function/)

  `<?php 
    $unique_value = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
    header("x-mod-nonce: " . $unique_value);`

You can also set a string with a similar pattern to the one mentioned in the question with something like this:

```
$pattern = bin2hex(random_bytes(10)) . "-" . bin2hex(random_bytes(10)) . "-" . bin2hex(random_bytes(10)) . "-" . bin2hex(random_bytes(10))
```

Comment: Thank you @LucasMeine. Does the format of uniqid() needs to be like in the example of the documentation as I defined it above and if does, how to write it with this fuction?

Comment: If the generated token is for security (which nonce's usually are), use `random_bytes()` instead if `uniqid()` (which is not cryptographically secure)

Comment: Good suggestion, I will add it to my answer @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @Johnn I don't really know what documentation you are using, so I can't really answer this =/ but try it! See if it works :D

Comment: I would remove any reference to `uniqid()` since it's not a good function to use in this situation. You also need to convert the result of random_bytes() to ascii characters. It can be done by converting it to hex with `bin2hex()` like this: `bin2hex(random_bytes(16))` where `16` is the amount of bytes you want to get back.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson agreed.